# If $g\in L1$ and the inner product with all $L^2$ functions is finite, is it true that $g\in L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space.  Is it true that if $g\in L^1$ and $\int fg\,d\mu \leq C(g)\| f\|_{L^2}$ for some constant $C(g)<\infty$ for all $f\in L^{\infty}\cap L^2$ then $g\in L^2$?

This question is just out of curiosity, I feel this should be true but I have no idea how to prove/disprove it.

Comment: Just integrabilty if $fg$ for all $f \in L^{2}$ implies that $g \in L^{2}$. This question has been answered many times on SE.

Comment: I see! I guess that's the reason for the downvotes. I checked before making the question but I guess I didn't phrase it exactly inthis way. Could you point out to these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite, let $g_{n}=g\chi_{(|g|\leq n)\cap Q_{n}}$, where $Q_{n}$ is of finite measure such that $Q_{n}\uparrow X$, then $g_{n}\in L^{2}$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\|g_{n}\|_{L^{2}}=\sup\left\{\left|\int fg_{n}\right|:f\in L^{\infty}\cap L^{2},\|f\|_{L^{2}}\leq 1\right\}\leq C(g).
\end{align*}
By Monotone Convergence Theorem, one has
\begin{align*}
\int|g|^{2}=\lim_{n}\int|g_{n}|\leq C(g)^{2}<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: You're a genius! Is this a known result? Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually some mathematical analysts take it for granted in their manuscript writing, no title is given. Some graduate school qualifying exams also prefer to ask similar problem as this.

Comment: Thanks so much!